# UNION two tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've got a `TICKET` table, where the user can link the record with a `Supplier_ID` from `SUPPLIER` table or he can input a supplier name manually (its `Supplier_ID` = 0) for a quick ticket record to avoid creating a supplier record (fill in like 20 supplier fields) for a one in a lifetime supplier purchase .

```
Ticket_ID | Supplier_ID  | Supplier
--------------------------------------
1         |       0      | A Company
2         |       0      | Inc. Co
3         |      10      | 
4         |      1       |
```

And the `SUPPLIER` table looks like (plus other 20 fields)

```
Supplier_ID | Supplier
-------------------------
1           |  A Company
2           |  B Company
3           |  C Company 
4           |  D Company
```

Now I want to feed an autocomplete textbox with each unique Suppliers (all from SUPPLIER table and those names in `TICKET` table which Supplier_ID=0 BUT DO NOT MATCH with any of the Supplier names from SUPPLIER

So far, I've got in MS ACCESS SQL

```
SELECT Supplier_ID, Supplier FROM SUPPLIER

UNION ALL

SELECT Supplier_ID, Supplier FROM TICKET WHERE Supplier_ID = 0 AND Supplier <> '' GROUP BY Supplier, Supplier_ID
```

Output

```
Supplier_ID | Supplier
-------------------------
1           |  A Company
2           |  B Company
3           |  C Company 
4           |  D Company 
0           |  A Company 
0           |  Inc. Co.
```

Works almost OK, except there are two A Company (one with supplier_id 1 and one with 0). Which I would like to avoid adding the duplicate one with ID=0

Is it possible?

Comment: you don't need a union.. you need a left join group by and max

Comment: he does need a union because unmatched entries are possible on both sides.  Just needs to filter, as the answer which just popped up does

Comment: well looks to me a badly designed database... how come you have two supplier columns?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I edited the second select with WHERE Supplier_ID = 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to exclude any suppliers from the first part of the query.  So:

```
SELECT Supplier_ID, Supplier
FROM SUPPLIER
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT Supplier_ID, Supplier
FROM TICKET as t
WHERE t.Supplier <> "" AND
      t.Supplier NOT IN (SELECT s.Supplier FROM Supplier as s);
```